# Where can I visualize the "description" field when inserting a session using the REST API in the Google Fit App?

Tags: rest, google-fit, google-fitness-api

Where can I visualize the "description" field when inserting a session using the REST API in the Google Fit App?

Using the example provided by Google
{
"id": "someSessionId",
"name": "My example workout",
"description": "A very intense workout",
"startTimeMillis": 1396710000000,
"endTimeMillis": 1396713600000,
"version": 1,
"lastModifiedToken": "exampleToken",
"application": {
"detailsUrl": "http://example.com",
"name": "Foo Example App",
"version": "1.0"
},
"activityType": 1
}

The activity is inserted correctly, but in the App, the "description" field is missing; I can´t find where it is shown.

If I create a new activity in the App, the notes description is shown in the activity below its name.